# Take input from user until tic-tac-toe game ends

Tags: haskell, state, monads

So I'm about eight weeks through [CIS194](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html), and I'm making a super simple tic-tac-toe game in Haskell. I've got most of the game logic down, but I am stumped at the user input part.

As of right now just to check everything out I have this awful system of hardcoding the moves of the user and the computer.

```
putStrLn "Welcome to tic tac toe. Where do you want to move first?"

let board1 = emptyBoard
putStrLn (show board1)
loc1 <- getLine
let moveLoc1 = read loc1
let board2 = findAndReplace board1 (Left moveLoc1) (Right O)

...

let board7 = makeXMove board6
putStrLn (show board7)
loc4 <- getLine
let moveLoc4 = read loc4
let board8 = findAndReplace board7 (Left moveLoc4) (Right O)


putStrLn (show board8)
```

What I am aiming for, though, is that it will take user input, check if the game has ended, make the computer move, check if the game is over and repeat if not. In an imperative language I would wrap something like this in a while loop, but I am not sure how to approach the problem in Haskell.

From what I've looked at online, there are a lot of things that sound like they might help, but I don't know where to start with them. For example, I'm also looking at [this example](http://projects.haskell.org/operational/examples/TicTacToe.hs.html), and I've heard a lot about `Monad`s and `State` but is there any introductory literature I can take a look at to wrap my head around the whole thing?

All the code I have so far can be found [on github](https://github.com/2016rshah/TicTacToe).

Basically my question is how can I ask the user for input until the game ends and stop asking them when it does?

Comment: In Haskell you normally use recursion in such situations.

Comment: How do I pass the game board along the recursion? And how does the recursion work within the `main` function?

Comment: @2016rshah Recursion can be value-based. Write a function that produces an IO action that calls itself, or just refer back to `main` again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the board along into the recursive call

```
player :: Board -> IO ()
player board1 = do
    putStrLn (show board1)
    loc1 <- getLine
    let moveLoc1 = read loc1
    let board2 = findAndReplace board1 (Left moveLoc1) (Right O)
    if over board2                    -- check to see if the game is over and we should stop recursing
    then putStrLn (outcome board2)    -- what to do when the game is over
    else computer board2              -- recurse for the other player if the game isn't over
--       |        ^-- the state of the board being passed to the recursive call
--       ^----------- the recursive call to the other player


computer :: Board -> IO ()
computer board1 = do
    let board2 = makeXMove board1
    if over board2                    -- check to see if the game is over and we should stop recursing
    then putStrLn (outcome board2)    -- what to do when the game is over
    else player board2                -- recurse for the other player if the game isn't over
--       |        ^-- the state of the board being passed to the recursive call
--       ^----------- the recursive call to the other player
```

You will need to fill in the functions `over :: Board -> Bool` that detects when the game is over and `outcome :: Board -> String` that describes the outcome of the game. You'd start the game with the player going first with

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome to tic tac toe. Where do you want to move first?"
    player emptyBoard
```

There's a lot of code repeated in `player` and `computer`. A good challenge for yourself would be to figure out how to get rid of that duplicated code. Can you change `player` so that it doesn't know about `computer` and vice-versa and then make two `player`s play against each other (possibly slightly modified to tell which one's `X` and which one's `O`)?

Comment: The solution makes perfect sense now, thank you so much!